# Data driven pages for multiple frames

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, data-driven-pages, data-frame

I would like to produce series of maps with three different base maps. Within each data frame I have the same point shapefile with 1000 locations. Data driven pages allows only to produce maps from one frame. This means that in the resulting pdf only locations from first frame is changing and not for other two frames. I found that this could be done using ArcPy.

Could someone help me please with a simple example?

Are there also another possibilities without coding?

[image: data driven pages]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about setting the second and third frame extent as dependant from the first one (in arcmap), and set your DD pages on the first frame? 
As your data driven pages flick through the features in the first frame, the second and third frame will adjust to the same extents.

[image]

Comment: I was just discussing this technique earlier this week.